# Test exit() with boost unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'd like to ask, if it is somehow possible to test `exit()` or maybe test return code with Boost Unit Test library?

Comment: I just can tell it's possible with google-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is BOOST_CHECK_THROW() to verify that an exception (of a certain type) is thrown.  You usually shouldn't be calling exit() in your library code at all--throw exceptions and let the higher levels of the call stack decide whether to exit or not.

Boost Test expects to be able to control the "main" application itself, so if you call exit() I'm not really sure what you would want Boost Test to do next.  Trap the exit() call and not let the program exit?  What if your library actually depended on exit() working normally?